# how do I open links in the same wkwebview instead of a new browser (phonegap)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a phonegap app where I'm using the phonegap-ios-template to start it off, and I've redirected the app to open a website, say https://google.com

When I click on any link inside the app, it opens in a new browser window, as opposed to staying in the app. (i.e. there is a second screen that looks like a browser, has 'back to sampleapp' in upper lefthand corner, looks like a new session)

I'm trying to prevent this as I have a sample ios app which doesn't do this (it's just a single wkwebview, and I can navigate inside the app).

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer!

Started here:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/8647991#8647991

Realized that all links were being requested to open in a browser, so following the advice of the forum user, I just removed the two `<allow-intent>` http lines and voila it worked!

Additional reference here:

https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/508